# Centroid of a set of positions on a toroidally wrapped (x- and y- wrapping) 2D array?

Tags: python, algorithm, math

I have a flat Euclidean rectangular surface but when a point moves to the right boundary, it will appear at the left boundary (at the same y value). And visa versa for moving across the top and bottom boundaries. I'd like to be able to calculate the centroid of a set of points. The set of points in question are mostly clumped together.

I know I can calculate the centroid for a set of points by averaging all the x and y values. How would I do it in a wrap-around map?

Comment: Are your points guaranteed to be adjacent?  If not, how do you define the centroid of two points on exactly opposite sides of the torus?

Comment: They are mostly adjacent. Not necessarily though. If there are points on completely opposite sides then that axis doesn't matter any more for the problem and I just need the other axis.

Answer (score 1):

If cluster size is relatively small (smaller than half of grid), you can use simple approach:

Let's surface width and height are W and H. Imagine that the surface dimensions are tripled, so you have -W..2*W and -H..2*H axis ranges. Unroll wrapped values.

```
 XMin = X[0];  XMax = X[0]
 the same for Y

 for i = 1..N-1
    Check distance from X[i] to XMax and XMin
    Get largest of them D
    If D is larger than W/2, shift X[i] by W
    //example1: W=100, Xmin = 70, XMax = 90, X[i]=10 => X[i]=20+100 = 120 
    //example2: W=100, Xmin = 5, XMax = 12, X[i]=98 => X[i]=98-100 = -2 
    the same for Y
    update Min/Max
    Calc (W + Average(X[i])) %% W  //modulo operation
```

Answer (score 0):

I've done this before for Ramachandran plots. I will check but I seem to remember the algorithm I used was:

1. Assume that your Euclidian area has an origin at (0,0)
2. Shift all the points in a set so that they are fully within the area
3. Calculate the centroid
4. Shift the centroid back by the reverse of the original

So, say your points are split across the X axis, you find the minimum X-coordinate of the point set that is larger than the midpoint axis of the area. Then find the distance *d* to the edge on the Y axis. Then shift the entire cluster by *d*.